# Youtube API video listing, how long time for refresh cache?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

So I have something as simple as:

```
        $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
        $yt->setMajorProtocolVersion(2);

        $q = $yt->newVideoQuery();
        $q->setOrderBy('viewCount');
        $q->setCategory('182);
        $q->setAuthor('MYYOUTUBENAME');

        printVideoFeed($yt->getVideoFeed($q));
```

Which works just fine.

Now I am uploading more videos, which have been processed and is public - but they are not showing up on the above outputted list.

Its like the above query is stuck on the same cache, and wont refresh and load the new videos that has the keyword "182" from the user MYYOUTUBENAME ?

I have tried to change the video title of the videos that are showing, and also this wont refresh, it shows me the old video title?

Can i somehow affect this and make youtube refresh its cache, or is it something that youtube do? If last statement is the answer, then how long between the refreshes? Waited about 45 min now, still nothing.

Comment: Also tried to remove the setCategory() to load all from the user, but still only showing the same existing videos with their old video title

Comment: Now my existing videos have updated their VIDEO TITLE with the new one i gave them. But it still does not show the new videos with the same keyword 182 from same user ??

Comment: And now if i take a existing video and change keyword to 182 then it will appear after about 10 minutes. But still nothing for the new uploaded videos, uploaded about an hour ago almost, not appearing

Comment: UPDATE: Now the new videos are in the list! Yay! (After an hour exactly, we now know) But answer for this question, could be a source from Youtube or Google, which tells about this refreshing/cache time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Basically, you need to request videos from your uploads feed, not from the search feed, and make sure you don't provide any ordering parameters when making your uploads feed request.)